# How can i use RedirectToAction within $.ajax POST?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I'm trying to redirect with the following method of the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateSchedinaB([FromBody]ListAssociazioni listAss)
    {
        var userr = await _manager.GetUserAsync(User);
        var listSchedine = await _context.Schedine.ToListAsync();

        List<Associazioni> listAssocia = new List<Associazioni>();
        Schedine schedina = new Schedine();

        bool doppione = false;

        foreach (var item in listSchedine)
        {
            if (listAss.NomeS == item.Nome)
            {
                doppione = true;
            }
        }
        if (doppione == false)
        {
            schedina.Nome = listAss.NomeS;
            schedina.KsProfile = userr.ProfileId;
            schedina.Id = _context.Schedine.Count() + 1;
            _context.Schedine.Add(schedina);
        }
        else
        {
            ViewData["Success"] = "Data was saved successfully.";

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        foreach (var item in listAss._listAssoc)
        {
            var giocata = _context.Giocate.Where(c => c.Id == item.KsGiocata).First();
            var partita = _context.Calendario.Where(c => c.Id == item.KsPartita).First();

            Associazioni tmp = new Associazioni { KsGiocataNavigation = giocata, KsPartitaNavigation = partita, KsSchedinaNavigation = schedina };
            _context.Associazioni.Add(tmp);
        }
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

I don't call the method with an asp-action in the view but with in $.ajax post in this way:

-VIEW:

```
`<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="schedine.Nome" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input id="nomeSchedina" asp-for="schedine.Nome" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="schedine.Nome" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>


<a class="btn btn-default" onclick="InviaServer()" >CREA</a>`
```

-JS:

```
function InviaServer() {
    var Nomes = $("#nomeSchedina").val();
    if (Nomes == "" || Nomes == null) {
        window.alert("Dai un nome alla tua schedina!");
        return;
    }
    var listadef = {"NomeS": Nomes, "_listAssoc": json};
    $.ajax({    // Send list to controller
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        url: "/Logged/CreateSchedinaB/",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(listadef),
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}
```

CONTROLLER - INDEX

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

The problem is that the method does not redirect to the page but sends the page in the browser console ... why?

Sorry my english ... I'm an "absolute beginner"

Comment: Are you trying to call different action in controller

Comment: and where is you "index" action?

Comment: in the same controller

Comment: Everything works but the page prints in console.

Comment: can you add here your index action problem can be there

Comment: Like a console.log (index.html)

Comment: do you want to return a view in index ?

Comment: Send the redirect Url to the client and then do a `location.href = redirecturl` on the client.

Comment: I did not understand sorry ... would you like to see the problem? (console)

Comment: yes i guess you should add index action codes

Comment: Yes sorry, i will return a view!

Comment: OK, I do it right now

Comment: I'll try Siva, thanks!

Comment: It does not return a view bacause you are using jquery ajax.

Comment: if you want to page redirect with refresh dont use ajax

Comment: Yes but with ajax i send a json variable at the server..

Comment: The server use the variable to create database rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make an Ajax call, you are responsible to handle the response from server. For your case you can something like following.:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoSomeStuffAndRedirect()
{
     //Do some stuff you want

     return Json(Url.Action("Contact"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
     //Note: Url.Action(...) would give you fully qualified url based on to an action and it adheres to the defined route templates.
}
```

On Client side you can do:

```
$.ajax({    // Send list to controller
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            url: "/Home/DoSomeStuffAndRedirect/",
            type: "POST",
            data: {},
            success: function (response) {
                location.href = response;
            }
});
```

Hope this give you some idea to start with.

Comment: I can't use JsonRequestBehavior becouse i don't find System.Web.Mvc references... help

Comment: Without `JsonRequestBehavior` also it should work for your case. I am curious, why it is not available for you because without `System.Web.Mvc` references you wouldn't be this far on your MVC experiments!

Comment: `return Ok(jsonObject)`

Comment: Maybe because i use AspNetCore?

Answer (score 0):

You do an ajax call, it cannot redirect you to something else.

You need to use something like this in ajax success:

```
 success: function (response) {
         document.location = '/Logged/index/';
        }
```

Also in a backend method CreateSchedinaB don't redirect (it is usless, just return something to your ajax method response, for example about results for  redirect, or errors)

Comment: Thanks, this answer was very useful, but I need to redirect it from the controller because I do a check!

Comment: do a check in your controller and then report the check status back to oyour ajax, based on that do a redirect or show errors.